# WPF Using the Tag Element to Bind a Color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates

I want to create a Slider that has a Gradient from Black to a certain Color as a Background.
The color is to be set additionally to the Style of the Slider. AFAIK, no extra properties can be added to a given control using just Control Templates (i.e. no attached properties and no derived controls).

I therefore want to use the Tag property and have created this snippet:

```
<Style x:Key="ColorSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Offset="0.0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1.0"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>

                        ....
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and use it like this:

```
<Slider Style="{StaticResource ColorSlider}" Width="100" Height="500" Tag="{StaticResource redColor}"/>
```

with `redColor` beeing a static resource (although I'd prefer typing colors directly using HEX codes or predefined colors).

This however doesn't work, any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using **`TemplateBinding`** which gets resolved at compile time, use **`RelativeSource`** with Mode set to **`TemplatedParent`** which gets resolved at run time.

TemplateBinding gets resolved at compile time but actual value for tag will be resolved at runtime when staticResource gets applied. That's why you should use another approach.

```
<GradientStop Color="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                       Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Offset="0.0"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. However could you explain, why it is important that the binding in this case gets resolved at runtime and not compiletime?

Comment: Added more details to an answer.